# What is the difference between these two SQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I've created table Address with this SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Street` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Number` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `other_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`other_id`) REFERENCES `other` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

But there's also this query:

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Street` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Number` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `other_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `other_id` (`other_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `adress_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`other_id`) REFERENCES `other` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci$$
```

and it seems that booth query create identical tables.

So can anyone explain to me what does this line do:

```
KEY `other_id` (`other_id`),
```

and what is the difference between these two lines:

```
  FOREIGN KEY (`other_id`) REFERENCES `other` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
and
  CONSTRAINT `adress_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`other_id`) REFERENCES `other` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

If the difference between last two lines is that latter gives name 'adress_ibfk_1' to foreign key ? If that's true - should I do it ? I mean, why should I name foreign keys ? Will I ever need their names ?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: All developers on your project will hate you forever if you don't fix the name of the table to spell Address correctly.

Comment: @HLGEM: Oh, I assumed it was the location where a single item of women's party attire was being stored.

Comment: @HLGEM - Unless the table names are in Swedish:). But since field names are not in Swedish you are probably correct.

Comment: how many addresses do you think you'll be storing in that MASSIVE UNSIGNED BIGINT ? Your other datatypes also need addressing !!

Comment: OMG to you all :D this is just stupid table to describe my question ... and yeah, I've misspelled address ...

Comment: @f00 : well I don't see why using bigint on all tables is a problem on a small project ? Anyway, what other datatypes you think I should adjust ? What datatypes would you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL interprets `KEY` as an index, so the second query creates an index on the column `other_id`.

The difference between the two FK declaration is that you manually set the name in the second line. In the first line, MySQL automatically sets a name.
They do need names, but you don't necessarily have to be aware of them. Some more advanced RDBMS use them to be more explicit when a query raises an error.

Comment: Thank you !! But first query also creates index on column other_id. So does it get create even if I don't specify it, just like FK get's it's name ?

Comment: xx77aBs : I'm not sure, but MySQL most likely creates automatically an index on FK columns.

Comment: So it isn't a rule ? I mean, there could be RDBMS that won't create index on FK columns automatically ?

Answer (score 2):

`KEY` is a synonym for `INDEX`, so that is creating an index on the `other_id` column.

The only difference in the foreign key construction is that the latter `constraint` version allows you to name the constraint, whereas the former will be given a system generated name.

This name can be seen in the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLE_CONSTRAINTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/table-constraints-table.html) table.